# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'

Tags: django

I´m trying to make a cron inside my django app with django-crontab==0.7.1,.
Within my project settings installed apps, crontab app first, and then my app, both registered.
In my cron.py:

```
from .models import Url

urls=Url.objects.values_list('url')

def foo(url):
    if url not in urls:
        link= Url(
            url=url,
        )
        link.save()
foo('https://example.org')
```

Also tried to put inside cron.py, but it doesn´t make sense since both are inside same app

```
from foo.models import Url
```

Also  **init**.py inside app

My models.py inside foo app, after migrations ran

```
from django.db import models

class Url(models.Model):
    url=models.URLField('url',blank=False,null=False)
```

but still getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
Sorry if this has been asked before, but nothing watched yet gives me the answer

Thank you

Comment: Could you comment on how you are running your code?

Comment: @Brian, I'm running It from console, since I'm on Windows, Hoping cron works then just as fine as console, is that a problem?

Comment: If you're running `cron.py` directly as a top-level script (e.g. via `python3 foo/cron.py`), then it won't be aware of the package structure, so relative import won't work. For that you'll need to run it as a submodule of the `foo` package via `python3 -m foo.cron`.

Comment: See also [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/11082165)

Comment: If I do that, i get django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the 
environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings. For that solved with import os,django
os.environ.setdefault ("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "base.settings") 
django.setup(). But still have the doubt if cron will do the work, as I´m copletely lost on linux, crons, and bash

Comment: Your project has a apps folder to place the apps our everything is the same level as manage.py?

Comment: Please show your **`settings.py`**